# Regex for Google Analytics Goal Conversion Funnel

Tags: regex, google-analytics, goal-tracking, conversion-tracking

Setting up Google Analytics Goal conversion funnel, concerned that Step 1 and Step 2 could fire twice, what is the proper Regex to discreetly identify these steps?

Current code:

Step 1 Homepage:

```
.*sitename.com
```

Step 2 Checkout:

```
.*subscribe|abc123
```

GOAL Thank You:

```
.*\/subscribe\/.*\/show
```

SUPPORTING INFORMATION:

Step 1 is Landing page: "https://sitename.com" followed by nothing

note: the regex needs to eliminate any interior pages from match ie. "homepage.com/productname" etc.

Step 2 is checkout page:

"https://accountname.chargifypay.com/subscribe/abc123"

note: "abc123" is a static product number.

note: the URL MAY, but not always, be appended by event tags and ga tracking "?click=pre-order_countdown1&_ga=2.36488741.468562775.1549929587-14168953.1549612372"

GOAL is a thank you page:

It is unique in that it contains "/show", however, it also includes "/subscribe" and the product number "abc123" the same as in Step 2, however, it is not in the same order.

example:

"https://accountname.chargifypay.com/subscribe/khqjjnpp5sthnjxkn6pt6vqz/25706078/show/abc123"

note: "khqjjnpp5sthnjxkn6pt6vqz/25706078" is randomly generated

note: the url is not appended by any variables - it ends after the static product number "abc123"

```
.*sitename.com
.*subscribe|abc123
.*\/subscribe\/.*\/show
```

Expect to match discreetly match step 1, 2, Goal - but cannot tell if the matching is too broad.

I expect to see traffic in the real-time --> conversions view of Google Analytics under the respective goal.

[screenshot of Google Analytics Goal Detail Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxYCH.png)

[screenshot of real-time conversion goal view in Google Analytics successfully showing traffic at GOAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TZss.png)

Answer (score 0):

Found a pretty good tool for playing with URL Regex:
https://www.regextester.com/93652

Step 1, no issue.

Step 2 seems to be a fixed URL, which can be filtered by:
.*accountname.chargifypay.com/subscribe/abc123

Step 3 can be filtered by:
.*accountname.chargifypay.com/subscribe/.*/show/abc123